# Let $G=SO(3)$ and $\theta:G\to G$ defined by $\theta(g)=JgJ$ where $J=\text{diag}(-1,1,1)$. Prove that, $\theta(g)\in Kg^{-1}K$ where $K=SO(2)$

Tags: analysis, harmonic-analysis, locally-compact-groups, haar-measure, gelfand-representation

Here $K=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & T_1\end{pmatrix}:\ T_1\in SO(2)\right\}$. $K$ is a compact subgroup of $G$. The above problem is part of the proof of $(G,K) $ is Gelfand pair.

I've already prove that the above $\theta$ is involutive automorphism of $G$. But I'm unable to show that $\theta(g)\in Kg^{-1}K\ \forall g\in G$.

I know that $G=KAK$ where $A=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta & 0 & \sin\theta\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ -\sin\theta & 0 & \cos\theta\end{pmatrix}:\ \theta\in[0,2\pi)\right\}$. Can I anyone use this to attempt the problem?

Can anyone suggest me a wayout? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Hint:  $-Id$ commutes with everything.

Comment: $\theta (g)=(-J)g (-J)$ This shows that $\theta(g)\in KgK$. But I'm not getting how to conclude $\theta(g)\in Kg^{-1}K$.

Comment: Oh, I totally misread the question.  I thought you were asking to show that $\theta(g)$ is also given by conjugation by an element in $K$.

Comment: I've tried to make up for my earlier useless comment with a more helpful answer.  Let me know if you need any details filled in!

Answer (score 1):

Given $g \in G = SO(3)$, I'll use the notation $g_0$ to refer to the top right entry of $g$.  I'll also use transpose notation $(a,b,c)^t = \begin{bmatrix} a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$ to avoid writing such large lines.

Note that $g^{-1} = g^t$ and $(g^t)_0 = g_0$.  Moreover, $\theta(g)_0 = g_0$  Thus, what you want to show  follows from the following more general proposition.

**Proposition**:  Suppose $g,h\in G$ with $g_0  = h_0$.  Then there are $k_1,k_2\in K$ with $g = k_1 h k_2$.

**Proof outline:**  $1$.  Given an vector $(a,b)^t$, there is a rotation matrix $R = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta\\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$ with $R(a,b)^t =  (\lambda,0)^t$ for $\lambda = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}\geq 0$.  (When $\lambda > 0$, $\theta$ is uniquely determined).

$2$.  Given $g\in G$, there is an element $k_1\in K$ with the property that the first column of $k_1g$ is $(g_0, \lambda ,0)^t$ with $\lambda = \sqrt{1-|g_0|} \geq 0$.

$3$.  Given $g\in G$ having the form of 2. there is a $k_2\in G$ with $gk_2$ having first row $(g_0, \lambda, 0)$.  Moreover, note that $gk_2$ has the same first column as $g$.

Combining $2$ and $3$, we can find $k_1,k_2$ for which $k_1 g k_2$ has the form  $\begin{bmatrix} g_0 & \lambda & 0\\ \lambda & * & *\\ 0 & * & *\end{bmatrix}$.

$4a$.  Using orthgonality and $\det = 1$, show that if $g_0 \notin\{\pm 1\}$, then all four $\ast$ are determined by the other entries.

$4b$.  Using orthgonality and $\det  =1$, show that if $g_0\in \{\pm 1\}$, then we may further repick $k_1$ and $k_2$ so that $k_1 g k_2 = \operatorname{diag}(g_0,1,g_0)$.

$5$.  Thus, in either case, given $g\in G$, we can find $k_1,k_2$ with $k_1 g k_2$ in some "normal form" which is completely determined by $g_0$.  Thus, if $h\in G$ with $h_0 = g_0$, then $g$ and $h$ have the same normal form.  Conclude.  $\square$

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts. I have a query regarding 4a. How to show all the four entries are uniquely determined by $g_0$? I can show they are determined by $g_0$ but I am getting more than one solutions like $\pm$ of something.

Comment: @MathBS:  Doing row 1 $\cdot $ row 2 $=0$, if I am computing right, I find the top left $\ast$ to be $-g_0$.  Using the fact that length of row 2 $=1$ determines the top right $\ast$ up to sign, but if I am computing correctly, it's $\pm 0=0$.  Likewise for the bottom left $\ast$.  Then $\det =1$ determines the bottom right $\ast$.  I got $\ast= -1$ for that entry.  But maybe I have a computation error or two?